# How to set a GridPane to adjust automatically to content in JavaFX

Tags: java, gridview, javafx, scrollview

I have a `GridPane` inside of a `ScrollView`. I'm adding images in each space of the `GridPane`. First there is only 1 row and 3 columns. But when I pass the amount of 3 images, I increase the `GridPane` in one row and I add the number (`130px`) that represents the height of a grid row. So here is my code.

```
 private void AddItem() {
        ImageView image = new ImageView();
        image.setImage(new Image("media/logo.jpg"));
        image.setFitHeight(50);
        image.setFitWidth(100);
        if (columns > 2) {//when it reaches the end of the columns
            viewGrid.setPrefHeight(viewGrid.getHeight() + 130);//I increase the height of the GridPane
            viewGrid.addRow(rows++);//I add a new row
            columns=0;//I set the column to 0 again
        }

        viewGrid.add(image, columns, rows);
        columns++;
 }
```

#### Result

The images started to smash into each other instead of keeping the real position:

[image]

Is there some property in `GridPane` that allows me to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manually adjust the size of the `GridPane`. Use [`rowConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getRowConstraints--) instead. Those allow you to specify properties for a row, such as alignment and size constraints. The `GridPane` will automatically update it's height.

#### Example

```
private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = 3;
private int nextColumnIndex = COLUMN_COUNT;
private int currentRow = -1;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image image = new Image("http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a");
    
    GridPane imagePane = new GridPane();
    
    ColumnConstraints colConstraint = new ColumnConstraints(120);
    colConstraint.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
    
    RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints(130);
    rowConstraints.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
    
    // add constraints for columns
    imagePane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(colConstraint, colConstraint, colConstraint);

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(imagePane);
    scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
    scroll.setPrefSize(380, 300);

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scroll);

    Button btn = new Button("Add Image");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        ImageView newImage = new ImageView(image);
        newImage.setFitHeight(50);
        newImage.setFitWidth(100);
        if (nextColumnIndex >= COLUMN_COUNT) {
            nextColumnIndex = 0;
            currentRow++;
            imagePane.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);
        }
        imagePane.addRow(currentRow, newImage);
        nextColumnIndex++;
    });

    root.setLeft(new VBox(btn));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

By the way: The [`addRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#addRow-int-javafx.scene.Node...-) method is used to add children to a specific row, not for adding the row itself. A row is automatically added to the `GridPane`, if a `Node` with the index (or a larger index) is added as child. You need not create a row by calling a `GridPane` method.

---

Note that behaviour similar to the one you're trying to achieve is already implemented in [`FlowPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html). This would be an option to simplify your code. Just make sure the width of the `FlowPane` is chosen appropriately (i.e. allowing 3, but not 4 elements in a row).

#### Example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image image = new Image("http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a");

    FlowPane imagePane = new FlowPane();
    imagePane.setHgap(20);
    imagePane.setVgap(130 - 50);
    imagePane.setRowValignment(VPos.CENTER);
    imagePane.setColumnHalignment(HPos.LEFT);

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(imagePane);
    scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
    scroll.setPrefSize(380, 300);

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scroll);

    Button btn = new Button("Add Image");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        ImageView newImage = new ImageView(image);
        newImage.setFitHeight(50);
        newImage.setFitWidth(100);
        imagePane.getChildren().add(newImage);
    });

    root.setLeft(new VBox(btn));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, and it is much better than the other way. With this solution I don't need to uses indexes, so it makes it much more easy. Thank you.